# HTML5 Tile Cycle Puzzle

Tags: javascript, game, html5

It's been a while since I did anything with JavaScript. I made a tile puzzle game to help me brush up. You can find it here: https://compucademy.net/tile-puzzle/

I would like some feedback on my use of JS, HTML and CSS. Anything would be helpful - structure, best practices, overall approach, suggestions for improvement etc.

Any input much appreciated.

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const n = 16;
    const initialTileArray = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    initialTileArray.push( String( i + 1 ) );
    }
    const board = document.querySelector( '.game-board' );
    const audio = document.getElementById( 'audio' );
    const resetButton = document.getElementById( 'reset-btn' );
    const scrambleButton = document.getElementById( 'scramble-btn' );
    let selectedTiles = [];
    let clickNumber = 0;
    let scrambledTileValues = [];
    resetButton.addEventListener( 'click', resetGame );
    scrambleButton.addEventListener( 'click', scrambleTiles );

    function resetGame() {
    board.innerHTML = '';
    scrambledTileValues = initialTileArray.slice( 0 );
    createBoard();
    }

    function scrambleTiles() {
    board.innerHTML = '';
    scrambledTileValues.sort( () => 0.5 - Math.random() );
    createBoard();
    }

    function createBoard() {
    for ( let i = 0; i < scrambledTileValues.length; i++ ) {
        const tile = document.createElement( 'div' );
        tile.setAttribute( 'data-pos', i + 1 );
        tile.classList.add( 'game-tile', 'game-blue', 'text-center' );
        tile.addEventListener( 'click', processTile );
        board.appendChild( tile );
        tile.innerHTML = scrambledTileValues[i];
    }
    }

    function checkWin() {
    const tiles = board.childNodes;
    const config = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++ ) {
        config.push( tiles[i].innerHTML );
    }
    return JSON.stringify( config ) === JSON.stringify( initialTileArray );
    }

    function playSuccessSound() {
    audio.play();
    }

    function processTile() {
    const tilePos = this.getAttribute( 'data-pas' );
    if ( clickNumber === 0 || clickNumber === 1 ) {
        this.classList.remove( 'game-blue' );
        this.classList.add( 'game-red' );
        selectedTiles.push( this );
        clickNumber += 1;
    } else if ( clickNumber === 2 ) {
        selectedTiles.push( this );
        for ( var i = 0; i < selectedTiles.length; i++ ) {
        selectedTiles[i].classList.remove( 'game-red' );
        selectedTiles[i].classList.add( 'game-blue' );
        }
        window.console.log( this.getAttribute( 'data-pos' ) );
        const val0 = selectedTiles[0].innerHTML;
        const val1 = selectedTiles[1].innerHTML;
        const val2 = selectedTiles[2].innerHTML;
        selectedTiles[0].innerHTML = val2;
        selectedTiles[1].innerHTML = val0;
        selectedTiles[2].innerHTML = val1;
        selectedTiles = [];
        clickNumber = 0;
        if ( checkWin() ) {
        playSuccessSound();
        }
    }
    }
    resetGame();
} );
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <title>Tile Puzzle 3 | 3-Cycles</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
                <h1>Tile Puzzle 3 | 3-Cycles</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
                <p>Click 3 tiles to cycles their positions and solve the puzzle</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-">
                    <div class="game-board d-flex flex-wrap"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <button id="reset-btn" type="button" class="mt-3 game-btn">Reset</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button id="scramble-btn" type="button" class="mt-3 game-btn">Scramble</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <audio id="audio" src="assets/Success-sound-effect.mp3"></audio>
        <script src="scripts/puzzle3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

````
body {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
}

.game-board {
    width: 408px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.game-tile {
    font-family: monospace, monospace; 
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.game-btn {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: green;
}

.game-btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.game-blue {
    background: blue;
}
.game-red {
    background: red;
}

```
````

Comment: How about starting with a scrambled board?
Explaining what the cycle does (moves last clicked to first clicked position, etc.)?
A trial counter?
Congratulating player when solved?
Future:
Scoreboard?
Competition against others?
Leagues?
Prizes?
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stray `console`** You have `window.console.log( this.getAttribute( 'data-pos' ) );`. They're useful for debugging, but remember to remove logs for production. Consider [`no-console`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console).

**n** A variable named `n` is not all that informative. How about calling it `totalNumberOfTiles` instead? Also, rather than

```
for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
initialTileArray.push( String( i + 1 ) );
}
```

You can start at 1 instead of 0 to make the logic a bit easier:

```
for ( let i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfTiles; i++ ) {
  initialTileArray.push( String( i ) );
}
```

**Indentation** A number of places in your code aren't properly indented, making it slightly harder to read than would be ideal. Consider an IDE which can indent automatically, like VSCode - that way the code can be made to look pretty without any manual effort at all on your part.

**DOMContentLoaded?** Keeping code free of unnecessary indentation can make it more readable - or, at least, some prefer it that way. If you feel the same, you can remove the `DOMContentLoaded` listener entirely - the `<script>` is at the bottom of the body already, so all elements will surely exist by then. You can also put the script in the `<head>` and do the same thing - all you need to do is give the script the `defer` attribute.

**Biased sorting** You use `scrambledTileValues.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());`. This is a biased algorithm. For a long article on this, see [here](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html); the results will not be altogether random. To sort, use a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954).

**processTile bug** The same tile can be selected more than once. For example, click 1, 1, then 2. The result is the 2 disappearing entirely; there are now two 1s on the board. Change `processTile` so that, if the clicked element is in `selectedTiles` already, do nothing. (Or deselect it, decrement `clickNumber`, and remove it from the array)

**Pointer?** Tiles are clickable. You might make this clearer by giving them `cursor: pointer`.

**Color toggling** Rather than having one class for blue and another for red, consider having just a base color (blue) with one class that gets toggled (red when on):

```
.game-tile {
  background: blue;
}
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

That way, in the JS, you only have one class to toggle, not two.

**Avoid `var`** You're using ES6, which is great. In ES6, there's no reason to use `var` - use `const` instead (or `let` when you must reassign). Consider a linter which will prompt you to [automatically fix](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-var) it.

Or, even better, instead of iterating manually and messing with indicies, invoke the collection's iterator instead:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++ ) {
    config.push( tiles[i].innerHTML );
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
for (const tile of tiles) {
    config.push( tile.textContent );
}
```

Which leads to the next point:

**Avoid `innerHTML`** - unless you're *deliberately inserting* or retrieving HTML markup, it's faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate to use `textContent` instead.

**Typo** You refer to `data-pos` twice, and `data-pas` once. You probably wanted `pos`.

Also, for data attributes, rather than `getAttribute`, it can be nicer to use the `dataset` property instead: replace

```
const tilePos = this.getAttribute( 'data-pas' );
```

with

```
const tilePos = this.dataset.pos;
```

(or you could remove it entirely, since it isn't used anywhere else)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That was exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. I've implemented all of that now and will remember the points in future.